# Pre Compile assets in different layout- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

In my rails application I have 3 layouts for different users. Every layout having some javascript and css files included in it.

I can't use following line in my application.js or application.css file

```
//= require_tree .  or  *= require_tree .
```

When I pre-compile all my js and css every thing is get disturbed in my site.

But I want to compile all my js and css files but compiling then together not working. Because when I compile all css files together then some of my classes are get override by other classes.

Even while pre compiling my assets its not giving me any error.

or I can only include those files in application.js or application.css which are common in 3 layouts. like this

```
//= require jquery-1.8.3
//= require jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js
//= require jquery-ui.js
```

But what if I to want pre compile my other js or css files which are not common in layouts?
Any Solution?

Comment: I got my solution from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563651/rails-3-1-exclude-js-files-from-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In config/environments/production.rb you can set, what do you want to precompile

```
config.assets.precompile << %w(admin.js admin.css user.js user.css)
```

Comment: Yes, but when i precompile all css files together some classes get override. I dont want that.

Comment: Give them specific names, some prefix to avoid overriding

Answer (score 0):

From whatever i can get i think you want to have a different layout for different users. what you should do is remove require tree from your application.css and application.js files and require all the files which you want to have in your entire app and then for specific users you can simply render that layout

Comment: I am rendering layout for specific user, but js or css which are not included in application file, How i can compile those files?

Comment: Ok sorry i got it wrong and coming back to your question why would you want a different css and js files. They only target your specified classes and id's. I think a better approach would be to add some prefix or suffix in your class and id to specify which user you want and then target those classes and ids